# Adding new columns in ag grid export excel

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

How to add new columns in ag-grid in the exported excel in reactjs. I think ag-grid dynamically export excel on right click. Where does this code exactly reside and how to edit it so that I can add an extra column only in exported excel.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to back-track from the `ag-grid` instance, the `ag-grid` instance is created as shown below,

```
new agGrid.Grid(divElement, gridOptions);

// divElement : document element for the grid
// gridOptions: param object having all grid related information
```

The `gridOptions` , will have column definitions in it, you can try disabling visibility of a column by setting column's `display` property i.e., `hide` to `false`, so that on export you have the column field. For more read refer [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/column-properties/#reference-display)